# Counting number of elements in an array of words using MIPS

Tags: mips

I am trying to code MIPS to count the number of elements in an array of words that are greater than x and less than y, but the code does not seem to branch properly and I keep getting "count = 9" which is, in this case, the number of elements in my list.

```
.text       
        .globl __start 
__start:        # execution starts here  */

la $a0, ans # load str "count ="
li $v0, 4
syscall     
            la $t0,nums    # load array into address
            li $t1,0      # setting counter to 0
            addi $s0, $zero, 50    # adding constant of 50
            addi $s1, $zero, 100   #adding constant of 100
            lw $t5,count           # loading word "9"
            
again :         lw $t4 ($t0)      # load first element of array into t4
                bgt $t4,$s0,passif50       #comparing if first element is greater than 50
                

passif50 :      blt $t4,$s1,passif100      #comparing if first element is less than 100
                

passif100 :     add $t1, $t1,1             #incrementing counter by 1
                add $t0, $t0,4             #increment current array element pointer
                sub $t5,$t5,1              #deincrement "count" word by 1
                beqz $t5,done              #when "count" word is equal to 0, exit loop
        
                
done :          move $a0,$t1
                li $v0,1
                syscall                # print the count

                li $v0, 10
                syscall                # end program
        

     .data          
nums:   .word 55,68,2,60,2000,51,99,1,67
count:  .word 9
ans:    .asciiz "count = "
endl:   .asciiz "\n"
```

Comment: Conditional branch to just the next instruction doesn't make sense. You will want to jump somewhere else.

Comment: Hmmm, your posted code doesn't contain loops and the count to print should be 1, if my understanding is correct. Is this your actual code? If not, please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I verified that your program prints "count = 1" with QtSpim. (I changed `__start` to `main` and breaked `.word` for `nums` to one integer per line to run on that)

Comment: If you are actually getting "count = 9" printed from this code, please tell us how you are running this code.

Comment: I must have done some modifications, I apologize. It is true that the new result is now 1. I do apologize for this (I am also running in QtSpim) What do you mean by "Conditional branch to just the next instruction doesn't make sense" if you are willing to elaborate :)

Comment: Considering this instruction `bgt $t4,$s0,passif50`, when `$t4 > $s0`, the execution will jump to `passif50`, which is `blt $t4,$s1,passif100`. when `$t4 <= $s0`, the execution will proceed to the next instruction, which is `blt $t4,$s1,passif100`. The same instruction (at the same address) is executed in both case, so this branch is meaningless. `blt $t4,$s1,passif100` and `beqz $t5,done` are also meaningless (effectively `nop` with prehaps some extra clock cycles consumed).

Comment: @MikeCAT thank you so much! With that little hint, I was able add bits of code that made this work!